Whats the nature of the image formed at the eye piece of a newtonian telescope?
I came across a diagram in my textbook that mentions a newtonian telescope, but does not add on any sort of information. I consulted chatgpt, but it wasnt enough to clear my doubts.
Here is my problem : So the concave mirror forms a real and inverted image of (lets say, a star), point sized, the image forms at focus of the mirror, where there is a plane mirror to redirect the light rays of the image to the objective lens, so the plane mirror will not convert the real image to a virtual image, since it only redirects it to the convex lens at the objective lens, and the image remains inverted,and the lens magnifies the image so formed , hence a virtual image is formed,and the final image remains inverted and doesnt change its vertical orientation.First of all, is this even correct? (i have no source to confirm.)
second, my textbook asks whether the image formed at the eyepiece is real or virtual?
my answer is virtual, because well, the object (image redirected by plane mirror) is between F1 and the optical centre, which will result in a virtual image and magnify it, but my textbook says its a real image, and mentions the reason as it being a convex lens..my reasoning might be wrong, but how is it real image..?
i am aware that in majority of the cases,a convex mirror forms real and inverted image, but here, isnt the 'object' between F1 and O as i previously mentioned..? or is it that the image isnt always between F1 and O? but that wouldnt result in a magnified image, which is the purpose of the lens being there, right?
The primary mirror forms a real and inverted image, and due magnification by convex lens, its a virtual image.
i want to know if there are any faults in my reasoning, and whether my book is right or not.

FWIW, The "plane mirror" (a.k.a., "secondary mirror") is not located at the focus of the primary. It's a bit closer to the primary than that. The focus (the plane of the real image) is near the bottom of the "focusing tube" in which, the eyepiece sits.

"my textbook asks whether the image formed at the eyepiece is real or virtual?" Hint: The eyepiece is just a fancy magnifying glass. Is the image that you see when you look through a magnifying glass real? or is it virtual?

..its virtual in this case, where the image is magnified, isnt it? so is the image formed at the eye piece also virtual? (genuinely- whats the answer.? because I've been tweaking over this, i mean- there would be a reason why my book tells me its a real image, right? i just dont get it though.)

So, yes. You see a virtual image when you look into the eyepiece. It's a magnified version of the real image that is formed by the primary mirror and redirected by the secondary.

The lens in your eye forms an essential part of the telescope. The mirror forms a real image close to the eyepiece, and the eyepiece lens then forms a virtual image at infinity. Finally the lens in your eye forms a real image of that virtual image on your retina. That's how you can see the object that the telescope is pointing at. As Solomon says it's working like a loupe but you are using the loupe to look at the real image from the mirror.

I'm baffled that this was closed as homework. It is asking how a telescope works. How is that homework?

sorry- but this was one of the questions on my sample paper my teacher gave as homework, but i didnt get my head around the provided diagram, so might as well thought to learn how a newtonian telescope works, though its not been formally introduced to us. Thanks, your answer helped me wrap my head around this a bit easier

@Confusedaf Please include the diagram in the question.
